# How to figure out what event is being called in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ASP.NET, but on a certain page I am using regular html text boxes as the request is done with AJAX, rather than the traditional full page post back. My issue is that when the user fills out the last text box and presses enter the text box loses focus and the page scrolls all the way to the bottom.

I tried using the onblur event but it's not working, so I'm wondering what event is actually being called when the enter key is pressed(or any key for that matter).

I tried this:

```
$("#loginPass").blur(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) 
                $("#DealerLogin").click();
        });
```

I have firebug for Firefox but can't figure out how to look at what js related operations are firing.

Comment: `keydown`, `keypress`, and `keyup`; in that order.

Comment: `e` is an event object, and should contain the full context of the event it represents, including what triggered it (source element, type of trigger, etc...). Should be able to inspect that with Firebug.

Comment: @JCOC611 if you press e.g. [Tab], things become more complicated. blurred input gets keydown and newly focused input gets keyup.

Comment: @Marc, your absolutely right, I wasn't thinking when I tried to use e.keyCode on a non key event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't call myself a javascript expert, but this is what I would try.

When I get stuck, and don't know if or when my methods are being called , I fall back to using the trusty old "alert('in method 1');" technique to debug my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    alert("In document.ready()"); 

    $("#loginPass").blur(function(e) 
    { 
        alert("In loginPass.blur() with keycode = " + e.keyCode); 
    }); 

    $("#loginPass").keydown(function(e) 
    { 
        alert("In loginPass.keydown() with keycode = " + e.keyCode); 
    }); 
});
```

It certainly isn't an elegant technique, but is often revealing.  If you find none of your methods are getting called, I guess make sure your text box id correctly matches "loginPass".

Comment: This often helps. The downside is, you may need to test in different browsers. And in some browsers event order may be even random.

Answer (score 5):

In the Firebug scripts panel, you can click the pause button:

[image: Pause btn in Firebug]

Try it right before you hit enter, then step through the code.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that when the user fills
>   out the last text box and presses
>   enter the text box loses focus and the
>   page scrolls all the way to the
>   bottom.

Hmm. This is definitely not a default behaviour for browsers. You need to know, what does this and just catch this event or part of code.